# ヘルプ センター検索で「スタック・オーバーフローの行動規範」のスニペットが英語になっている

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, ヘルプ, 行動規範

### 不具合事象

「スタック・オーバーフローの行動規範」のページは日本語に翻訳されているにもかかわらず、[ヘルプ センター検索で表示されるスニペット](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=%E8%A1%8C%E5%8B%95%E8%A6%8F%E7%AF%84)が英語になっています。

[image: ヘルプ センター検索で表示されるスニペットが英語になっている]

リンク先である「[行動規範 - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)」では、当該文章は翻訳されています。

> ## 行動規範
>
> ### この行動規範は、親切に協力し合える、そしてお互いを尊重することができるコミュニティを形成するためのものです。
>
> 質問をするためにこのサイトを訪れた人も、知識を惜しみなく共有しに来たという人も、専門知識やアイデンティティに関わらず全ての人が温かく迎えられ参加できるコミュニティを共に作ろうではありませんか。

---

To Community Team

Bug: Our Code of Conduct is not translated in [search results](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=%E8%A1%8C%E5%8B%95%E8%A6%8F%E7%AF%84), although CoC itself is translated. Could you fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

行動規範のスニペットがヘルプセンターの検索結果に日本語で表示されるようになりました。現在は行動規範の全コンテンツ (日本語) の索引付けがサポートされ、全て検索可能になりました (以前はそうではありませんでした)。同じ問題がポルトガル版、スペイン語版、およびロシア語版SOサイトに存在しましたがそれらも修正済みです。